# QListView with a QStandardItemModel and checkbox-enabled QStandardItems: How to capture *only* check-state changes?

Tags: qt

I have the following (simplified) code to add `QStandardItem`'s to a `QStandardItemModel`, attach the model to a `QListView`, and connect signals of my choice from the model to a function of my choice:

```
// MyUIContainer derives from QWidget
MyUIContainer::SetItems()
{
    // Inside a member function where model/items are added to a QListView...

    // This code does not show deletion of existing ItemSelectionModel

    QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(ui->listView);

    // In the real code, data is set in each QStandardItem
    model->setItem( 0, new QStandardItem() );
    model->setItem( 1, new QStandardItem() );
    model->setItem( 2, new QStandardItem() );

    connect(model,
            SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)),
            this,
            SLOT(ReceiveChange(QStandardItem*)));

    // I have also tried connecting to this signal - same problem described below
    //connect(model, SIGNAL(dataChanged(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &, const QVector<int>)), this, SLOT(ReceiveChange(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &, const QVector<int>)));

    ui->listView->setModel(model);
}

MyUIContainer::ReceiveChange(QStandardItem * item)
{
    // Problem!  This slot is called *three times*
    // whenever the check state of an item changes
}
```

As the code comment indicates, there is a problem: The `itemChanged()` \ `ReceiveChange()` signal \ slot combination is called **three** times whenever the check state of a checkbox in the `QListView` changes **once**.

I understand that I can create my own Model class that is derived from `QAbstractItemModel`, and (if I understand correctly) handle mouse clicks in the view myself, emitting signals such as, for example, the `itemChanged` signal with a proper user-defined role so that a change in checkbox state can be handled only once.

However, the latter approach requires me to be careful to handle all possible scenarios of mouse clicks & keyboard events that could result in a changed checkbox state.  I was hoping, and assuming, that this logic has been handled inside the Qt library itself, so that I don't have to - so that I can simply receive a signal (or some other message) when the check state of a checkbox changes.

Note that it seems that `QListWidget` (rather than `QListView`) also has exactly the same problem.

So, my question is: Without writing my own Model class derived from `QAbstractItemModel` - with its requirement that I myself write code to handle every possible way that a check state can change - how do I capture a changed check state (via a signal or otherwise) such that I can unambiguously capture every time a check state changes **once and only once** per check state change?

**ADDENDUM**

With apologies - as I took great care in ruling everything else out - Riateche's comment made it clear to me that the behavior is not *supposed* to work in the way this question highlighted.  Finally, I have indeed tracked down the problem to the fact that I was calling `connect()` multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in your slot and see where the three signals comes from? I have the weird feeling that it might be the same item with three roles changing, but only peeking at Qt's source code can tell.

Comment: I can't reproduse your issue. Everything is working perfectly, slot is called once per checkbox change. I assume your mistake is in the rest of your code. Also, if you would want to reimplement `QAbstractItemModel`, you definitely don't need to deal with mouse event etc. A view uses `QAbstractItemModel` interface only to interact with a model (more specifically, it calls `setData()` when user changes checkbox state).

Comment: Does the behavior change if you add a `Qt::UniqueConnection` parameter to your connect call?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  With apologies, and with your comments that the code *should* be working as I hope & expect, I have been able to finally track this down as a bug elsewhere in the code - `connect()` was being called multiple times.  I do apologize.  I have added an addendum.